# Trying to replicate rgeom() funtion

Tags: r, function, distribution

As an exercise, I'm trying to write a function which replicates the `rgeom()` function. I want it to have the same arguments and return values. I've started out by using `runif` to generate a vector with `x` elements, but I'm not sure how to apply the probability distribution:

```
rgeometric <- function(x, prob) {
    outcomes <- runif(x)
    
    P <- (1 - prob)^length(x) * prob
    return (P)
}
```

Would it be something like the following? How can I check that the distribution is geometric?

```
set.seed(0)
rgeometric <- function(x, prob) {
    outcomes <- runif(x)
    P <- (1 - prob)^length(x) * prob
    for (i in x) {
        x[i] <- x[i]*P
    }
    
    return (outcomes)
}

rgeometric(5, 0.4)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can accomplish this task using [Inverse Transform Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).
First, let's clear up some of your notation.
In the `rgeom()` function, we'll want that first argument to be `n`, an integer vector of length one giving the number of samples to generate:

```r
rgeometric <- function(n, prob) {
    u <- runif(n)
    ## do stuff
}
```

So how does inverse transform sampling work?
First we generate a vector **u** of standard uniform deviates, as shown above.
Then, for each element u<sub>i</sub> of **u**, we find the value of the inverse of the cumulative density function at u<sub>i</sub>.
For the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution), the CDF is `1 - (1 - prob)^(x+1)`; the inverse of the CDF is `ceiling(log(1-u) / log(1-prob)) - 1` ([link to derivation](https://www.ynufe.edu.cn/pub/tsxy/jhzhao/teach/CS/notes/lec3.pdf), p. 11).
So, we can complete the function like so:

```r
rgeometric <- function(n, prob) {
    u <- runif(n)
    return(ceiling(log(1-u) / log(1-prob)) - 1)
}
```

Your last question is how can we test if the resulting samples are distributed geometric?
I don't know of a formal test that will help, but we can see it *appears* to work when we compare the density of 1 million random draws from this custom function to the density of 1 million random draws from base R's `rgeom()` function:

```r
n <- 1e6
p <- 0.25
set.seed(0)
x <- rgeometric(n, p)
y <- rgeom(n, p)
png("so-answer.png", width = 960)
opar <- par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(density(x), main = "Draws from custom function")
plot(density(y), main = "Draws from base R function")
par(opar)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: ' I don't know of a formal test that will help' chi2 should work, why not?

Answer (score 0):

Note that for the definition of the geometric function implemented by r, the random variable is the number of failures until the first success. Therefore you could do:

```
my_rgeom <- function(n, p){
   fun <- function(p){
      n <- 0
      stopifnot(p>0)
      while(runif(1)>p) n <- n+1
      n 
     }
  replicate(n, fun(p))
}
```

Now test the function:

```
n <- 100000
p <- 0.25
X <- rgeom(n, p)
Y <- my_rgeom(n, p)
```

You can do a `ks.test` on X and Y, though this is for continuous variables. The best thing to do is the `chisq.test` to determine whether the two are similar.
Lastly we could use graphical methods. eg superimposed histogram:

```
barplot(table(X), col = rgb(0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.4))
barplot(table(Y), add = TRUE, col = rgb(1, 0.5, 0, 0.3))
```

[image]

From the image above you can see that the two are nearly identical